# maven profile for OS version range

Tags: java, maven

Is it not possible to define an OS version range in a maven profile?

```
<profile>
    <id>mac lion</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>mac</family>
            <version>[10.7.0,)</version>
        </os>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to define an OS range.

But you can attempt to achieve it by using the `<RequireOS>` parameter of [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html).  If this turns out to be tricky, you can try [writing a custom rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html).